# Charge a phone battery with TP4056

Tags: lithium-ion

Is it safe to charge a battery 'BLP657' using a module charger 'TP4056'?

Specifications: **BLP657**
Type: Lithium battery
Rated Voltage: 3.85V
Charge Limited Voltage: 4.4V
Capacity: 3300mAh
Rechargeable: Yes

Specifications : TP4056 
Charge module- Linear charging.
Current- 1A adjustable.
Charge precision- 1.5%.
Input voltage- 4.5V-5.5V.
Full charge voltage- 4.2V.
Led indicator- red is charging Green is full charged.
Input interface- micro USB.
Work temperature- -10° to +85°.
Inversed polarity- NO.
NOTE:

1. Ampere meter can only be connected to 5v input end of the module.
2. It is better that the charging current is 37% of the battery capacity. If you charge to the battery of 1000mAH, current of 400 is enough.
3. The connection wire should not be too thick.
4. Make sure the connect point is good.
5. If the input voltage is too high, like 5.2v, the current will be less than 1000mA, it is normal. It is protection function, auto-substract the charging cur

Comment: It depends. What current can the battery be charged with, and how large current the charger outputs? Please note that we don't know anything about the specs of the battery or module you are using, so if you want a specific answer, you must also provide the specific information to base the answer on.

Comment: @Justme thanks for the suggestion, i've updated the question.

Comment: A BLP657 appears to be for a OnePlus 6 phone - can you find out what the output current of the "official" charger is?

Comment: the output current for the official charger is 4A

Comment: It'll charge to 4.2V rather than the battery's rated 4.4V. While that may lose a few percent capacity, overall it's a good thing because it'll allow longer battery life.

Comment: 4A is a little beyond the comfortable zone for TP4056. Try to use a charger with 1 A or 2 A rating. Or keep a vigilant watch on the temperature of the TP4056 module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the specs you have given, it seems quite safe. I have been doing that with different Li-ion batteries.

You just have to make sure that the supply which you are using before TP4056 must have an output current limited to max 2A. Usual mobile phone chargers would be perfect for this.

Comment: Thanks for selecting this as the correct answered. If you tried this method, please share your experience as help to future users. Did the battery charged up satisfactory? Did the battery heat up? Did the TP4056 heat up during the charging?